# Repository-like injected object, initialize safely

Tags: java, dependency-injection, repository, guice, code-injection

I would like to create an object that basically functions as a list, and i will inject it in my services, using Guice

```
public class MyRepository {
  List<MyInterface> list = new ArrayList<>();

  public void add(MyInterface obj){
    list.add(obj);
  } 

  public List<MyInterface> get(){
    return list;
  }
}
```

Then i am gonna to be using injection from various points to add elements to this list

```
public class ObjectA implements MyInterface {
  @Inject
  public ObjectA(MyRepository myRepository){
    myRepository.add(this);
  }
}
```

My question is, i want to ensure that MyRepository is used in services only after all potential subscribers have been added.

Multibinder is not applicable because i will be needed some specific methods

Is there a way to do that? Thanks

Comment: What does your module look like? Or what do you plan it to look like? Personally I think that `multibinder` for `Set<MyInterface>` injected into `MyRepository` should not be an issue.  What specific methods do you think would stop this?

Comment: Hi, MyRepository has some methods that iterate the list of MyInterface, run a public Permissions get(User user) and gather the result of all of them as a list. Maybe i will make this a static method and use multibinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `multibinder` you're probably wanting to do something like this?  You don't want to use `static` as it would break the `@Inject MyRepository repository;` logic downstream.

Assuming you have your `multibinder` configured appropriately then your repository should work like this:

```
class MyRepository {
   Set<MyInterface> interfaces;

   @Inject
   public MyRepository(Set<MyInterface> interfaces) {
      // Here you can do some things like re-applying the interfaces to
      // a TreeSet (for example) if you needed to control priority.
      this.interfaces = interfaces;
   }

   public Set<Permissions> getPermissions(final User user) {
      // However you want to iterate through the interfaces
      return interfaces.stream()
            .flatMap(i -> i.getPermissions(user)) // maybe?
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
   }
}
```

You can have:

- Different methods for iterating the interfaces
- You can filter the interfaces based on other Interfaces.  For example if one `MyInterface` also extends `MyOtherInterface`

If I'm missing something, please update/comment and we can sort it out.

Comment: I will be honest, i do not remember why initially i didnt just use this solution. But it seems like the most logical and correct. Just make a wrapper with the extra methods. Thanks